# How to set default sort direction to descending for WPF DataGrid column?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid with sortable columns.  I do not want to pre-sort the grid on any particular column.  I just want the default sort direction when a user first clicks on a column header to be descending rather than ascending.

Neither SortDescription.Direction on a CollectionViewSource nor the SortDirection property of by DataGridTextColumns influence the default sort direction when changing the sort column.  It always chooses ascending on first click of a column header.

99% of the time it needs to be descending and switching columns in the user workflow is frequent, so this is adding a lot of unnecessary clicks.  I would highly prefer a XAML solution if there is one, but will resort to code trickery on events if necessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems you cannot do it without minor intervention into sorting handlers, because default sorting done by DataGrid starts like this:

```
ListSortDirection direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
ListSortDirection? sortDirection = column.SortDirection;
if (sortDirection.HasValue && sortDirection.Value == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
    direction = ListSortDirection.Descending;
```

So only if column was sorted before, and that sort was Ascending - it will flip it to Descending. However with tiny hack you can achieve what you want. First subscribe to DataGrid.Sorting event, and there:

```
private void OnSorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Column.SortDirection == null)
         e.Column.SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
    e.Handled = false;
}
```

So basically if there was no sort yet - you switch it to `Ascending` and pass it to default sorting of `DataGrid` (by setting `e.Handled` to `false`). At the beginning of sorting it will flip that to `Descending` for you, which is what you want.

You can do that in xaml with a help of attached property, like this:

```
public static class DataGridExtensions {        
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SortDescProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "SortDesc", typeof (bool), typeof (DataGridExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnSortDescChanged));

    private static void OnSortDescChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        var grid = d as DataGrid;
        if (grid != null) {
            grid.Sorting += (source, args) => {
                if (args.Column.SortDirection == null) {
                    // here we check an attached property value of target column
                    var sortDesc = (bool) args.Column.GetValue(DataGridExtensions.SortDescProperty);
                    if (sortDesc) {
                        args.Column.SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }

    public static void SetSortDesc(DependencyObject element, bool value) {
        element.SetValue(SortDescProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetSortDesc(DependencyObject element) {
        return (bool) element.GetValue(SortDescProperty);
    }
}
```

Then in your xaml:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" local:DataGridExtensions.SortDesc="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value}"
                            Header="Value"
                            local:DataGridExtensions.SortDesc="True" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

So basically you mark `DataGrid` itself with `SortDesc=true`, to subscribe to sorting event, and then you mark *only* that columns you need to be sorted desc. You can also bind `SortDesc` to your model if logic to determine this is there.

Comment: I had come to that solution as well, it works fine. Too bad I can't specify it in the XAML where I'm doing my binding as it is tough from the sort event to work back to the underlying bound data to determine whether to do this if you need it to work this way on just certain columns.

Comment: @DannyMeister I've updated my answer with helper attached property which will allow you to do this completely in xaml.

Comment: +1 This is a great answer. Two things: 1) You might also need to subscribe/unsubscribe the `Sorting` event handler based upon `e.NewValue`, which means moving the lambda to a named static method. 2) Why set `Ascending` in code? Shouldn't that be `Descending`?

Comment: Regarding my second point, I see why now: it tricks the existing sort handling code into thinking the column was already sorted ascending, so it flips it. I'm not 100% sure this doesn't double-sort the data though.

Comment: @DrewNoakes you might try to put a breakpoint in Sorting handler and if it is called once - I'd expect it is really sorted once.